# $\int \frac{du}{u-2}=-\int dx $ where's my stupid mistake?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm struggling with this very simple ode since it gives me 2 different solutions depending on where I put the minus.

from 
$$\int \frac{du}{u-2}=-\int dx $$
follows
$$ln|u-2|=-x +ln|C|$$ which yields
$$u=2+Ce^{-x}$$

Now if I rewerite the 1st equation to

$$\int \frac{du}{2-u}=\int dx$$
then
$$ln|2-u|=x+ln|C|$$
which gives
$$u=2-Ce^x$$

I know, there's probably a pretty stupid mistake, but I just can't see it.
any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you integrate the second integral, you forget the minus sign. That is, you should have:
$$ \int \frac{du}{2-u} = - \ln|2-u|.$$
(Recall the chain rule or integration using substitution. )

Comment: That's it! thank's.

Answer (score 1):

We can write $$\int \frac{du}{2-u} = - \int \frac{du}{u-2} = -\ln(u-2) + c$$

In order to expand the antiderivative’s domain, we then finally write: $$\int \frac{du}{2-u}=-\ln(|u-2|)+c$$